# Enviar el valor de un div o input a un formulario

Tags: javascript

Soy diseñador web y tengo una necesidad con un cliente. Creo que es simple por eso intentare hacerlo yo.

Mi cliente tiene un catalogo web. Cada producto tiene un codigo.
Como no es un ecommerce, necesito que al hacer clic sobre el producto se abra un formulario con datos para completar, pero con el codigo de ese producto ya puesto.

La parte del formulario la tengo. Lo que necesito saber es como traslado el valor de ese producto (que lo voy a tener puesto en un input o div), a un formulario que se encuentra en el mismo HTML, en un DIV flotante.
Creo que se puede hacer con javascript.

Gracias de antemano!

Lisandro

Comment: Creo que debes poner la parte que ya tienes para que te puedan ayudar mejor

Comment: Donde se encuentra el Id del producto?

Comment: El codigo es diferente si se trata de un div o un input, va a ser innerHtml, innerText o val(). Mejor pon el Html minimo en tu pregunta y lo que hayas intentado con Javascript.

Comment: Te recomiendo ver este enlace [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Tour -> [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Por favor coloca el código de ejemplo con el mejor intento que tengas hasta el momento. Posiblemente no es tu intención pero la impresión que da tu pregunta es que deseas una solución con 0 esfuerzo y así los usuarios de esta comunidad no estarán muy prestos a ayudarte. Es una sugerencia. Un Saludo!

Comment: Creo que tienen razon. Disculpen. Voy a elaborar mejor la pregunta.